# scrollIntoView() is scrolling to much down

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have test in selenium (using Python and FirefoxWebdriver). In test website I have table of records and I want to click on element in this table, but i have to scroll to this element and then I can click on it.

To scroll I'm using this method:

```
def scroll_to_element(self, element):
    try:
        self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

    except Exception as e:
        print 'error scrolling down web element', e
```

But this method scrolls to much down. Element is cca 2 lines upper and still isn't visible. Is there any other way, that scrolls corectly to the Element? I'm not experienced with these scripts at all.

Here is table:

```
<table id="idMainGriddata_columns" agname="data_columns" userid="1" entityidcolumnname="dc_id" editable="1" border="0" class="adodb_dbgrid" scrollx="0">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="25">
        # ...
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr entityid="14" class="adodb_dbgrid_even_row">
            <td class="centered" value="14">...</td>
            # ...
        </tr>
        # ... 400x tr
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is use of that method:

```
variable = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='idMainGriddata_columns']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), '" + column + "')]")
st.scroll_to_element(self, variable)
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(variable)
actions.double_click(variable)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Which exact element do you want to click? what's the column value?

Comment: I wan't double click that whole row (and I'm clicking on td element, that will access row that I want). I will edit my post.

Comment: Well i you want to click on the row make your xpath point to it, as now it points to td element.

Comment: Same result. I'm sad :(

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1**

If you only need to click the element you just can do:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='idMainGriddata_columns']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(), '" + column + "')]").click()
```

And if you have Js implemented for that it should scroll into it.

**Solution 2 (dirty way)**

If your column variable is integer:

```
column += 2
```

**Solution 3**

Add alignToTop to your scrollIntoView:

```
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Comment: solution 2 works fine, but I really need clearer way :/